# do I need custom Ord instance if I have custom Eq?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I had a data type that used to derive generic `Eq` and `Ord`:

```
data State = State (Set String) (Set String) deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

Then I created my own instance of `Eq`:

```
data State = State (Set String) (Set String) deriving Ord

instance Eq State where
    (State s0 s1) == (State s0' s1') =
        Set.union s0 s1 == Set.union s0' s1'
```

I am not sure if this breaks the `Ord` behavior and whether I need to create an instance of `Ord` too. Could someone please clarify?

Comment: it will not break the code but it will break the laws: you can try yourself with `State (fromList ["A"]) (fromList ["B"])` and `State (fromList ["B"]) (fromList ["A"])` - I think those are now `==` and `<` ...

Comment: If you have an `Ord` instance, you need an `Eq` instance. But you can have `Eq` instances without any `Ord` instance. Also: if you end up using this data type together with the `State` monad you will have to either import one of them qualified or rename your one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as I said in my comment you break the `Ord` laws here:

```
a :: State
a = State (Set.fromList ["A"]) (Set.fromList ["B"])

b :: State
b = State (Set.fromList ["B"]) (Set.fromList ["A"])
```

as now `a == b` and also `a < b`:

```
λ> a == b
True
λ> a < b
True
λ> b < a
False
```

see: `Ord` is supposed to be a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) and one law for those is

> a < b if and only if a ≤ b and a ≠ b

so of course you should fix it with the obvious choice for your own instance:

```
instance Ord State where
  (State s0 s1) <= (State s0' s1') =
    Set.union s0 s1 <= Set.union s0' s1'

λ> a == b
True
λ> b < a
False
λ> a < b
False
```